# listIterator cannot find symbol method listIterator()

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to iterate over a list using listIterator:

```
import java.util.*;

public final class FindMeetingQuery {
        public Collection<TimeRange> query(Collection<Event> events, MeetingRequest request) {
            Collection<TimeRange> free = new ArrayList<TimeRange>(); //when user is free
            ListIterator<Event> iterator = events.listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                     ...
```

However, I keep getting the error `cannot find symbol: method listIterator()`.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: even though `free` is an instance of `List` you've declared it (the variable) to be a `Collection` which doesn't define the `listIterator()`, change `Collection` to `List`

Comment: `Collection`class doesn't have a `listIterator()` method. Either use `iterator()` or use a different type of collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Collection` interface does not provide the `listIterator` method. It is, however, defined in other classes of the Java Collection Framework, such as `ArrayList`. You should change the type of the `events` variable if you want to use it.